# How does ansible module trigger particular linux commands?

Tags: linux, ansible

I would like to know how ansible module invoke particular command in linux machine.

Example: when we use module **user**, does this module trigger **useradd** or **adduser** in linux machine.

My use case is I want to limit sudo access to user that runs ansible scripts so that I can give only required permissions to particular user by adding following entry in /etc/sudoers.

```
%sftpadmin ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd,/usr/sbin/adduser,/usr/bin/passwd,/usr/sbin/usermod,/usr/sbin/groupadd,/usr/bin/chgrp,/usr/bin/chmod,/usr/bin/chown,/usr/bin/systemctl,/usr/sbin/service
```

if it ansible use any other way to perform tasks, let me know what can be done to minimise the user sudo access this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Long story short: you can't, [privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). This is a well known limitation of ansible.

Answer (score 1):

From the `ansible.builtin.user` module documentation:

> On all other platforms, this module uses `useradd` to create, `usermod` to modify, and `userdel` to remove accounts.

[Source](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/user_module.html#notes%5D)

But as Zeitounator said above, you cannot limit privilege escalation permissions to certain commands.